# Need Python to accept upper and lower case input

Tags: python, case-insensitive

I want my Python code to accept both uppercase and lowercase input.

I've tried casefold, but with no luck.  Any help?

```
advice =""
while advice !=("Yes"):
      print("Would you like some advice!")
      advice = input("Yes or No?    ")
print("Always listen to your IT Teacher!")
```

I would like the input to accept `Yes` and `yes` as user input.

Comment: Did you mean something like: `while advice.upper() !=("YES"):`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Here, we solve non-working code in a Q&A format. Please do some elementary research before posting a question. For more info on site policies, refer to the FAQ.

Comment: Note that none of the answers here would pass the [Turkey Test](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to let Python recognize both lower and uppercase input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719586/how-to-let-python-recognize-both-lower-and-uppercase-input)

Answer (score 4):

You could just make advice uppercase eg.:

```
while advice.upper() != "YES"
```

This way it doesn't matter if the user inputs lower or upper case (or a mix).

Comment: I would do the same with `.lower()` and `"yes"`, but that is probably a matter of personal choice.

Comment: True you could use lower() doesn't matter really.  Personally if I'm using a string constant I like to make it all uppercase to show that it is a constant but that's just me.

Comment: Thank you, sometime its the simplest things you cannot see, feel silly now!!