# How can I have python to accept lower or upper case input from the keyboard

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make my input were it will accept lower or upper case yes or no from the keyboard.

```
 a = input("Would you like to spin the wheel?Enter yes/no to continue\n")
    if a == "yes":
      play_game(count)

    if    a =="no":
            exit()
    else: 
    if    a != "yes" or a != "no":
            print_pause("Please enter in a valid input. yes/no\n")
            input()
```

Comment: instead of limiting input .. your if condition should check case-insensitively, i.e `if a.lower() == "yes"` and similarly `a.lower() == "no"`. or just replace a with `a = a.lower()` and then keep all checks in lower case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need Python to accept upper and lower case input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28406568/need-python-to-accept-upper-and-lower-case-input)

Answer (score 0):

Strings in python have a [`lower`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) method. Convert the input to all lower case and compare the result.

```
if a.lower() == 'no':
    ...
```