# How to let Python and HTML recognize both Uppercase and lowercase letters?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask

I have created a small app in python flask and in the html file,When i want to search a particular field it searches only after the case matches,ie if i want to search INDIA, it will only show the result when the case matches but when I search india or India it doesn't get searched? what could be the reason for not showing up the result?
I later found out from a stackoverflow answer that i need to convert it to uppercase first heres the answer [How to let Python recognize both lower and uppercase input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719586/how-to-let-python-recognize-both-lower-and-uppercase-input)

but how do include it over here?

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" name="search" placeholder="search"
                                       value="{{ request.form['search'] }}"></td>
```

in my py file its `if request.method == 'POST':
        search = request.form['search'].casefold()`
how would something in request.form['search'] get converted to either .casefold() or .upper() or .lower(). Please help me.

Comment: I hope you will find answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23195321/how-to-convert-string-to-uppercase-lowercase-in-jinja2).

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" name="search" placeholder="search"
                                       value="{{ request.form['search'].upper() }}"></td>
```

or

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" name="search" placeholder="search"
                                       value="{{ request.form['search'].lower() }}"></td>
```

basically what you have to do is convert the 'input' and 'whatever you are trying to match' in same case format ie. UPPERCASE or lowercase or Titlecase.
I guess you will also have to make same changes in your backend logic where you make actual search.

Comment: it doesn't work. changed my backend as well. it was like ```if request.method=='POST': search = request.form['search']``` so when i cross verify  it with printing the search. it doesnt change

Comment: yeah.... thats where you need to change actually

if request.method=='POST': search = request.form['search'].upper()

and if you are using sql to search something in database then use this:

"select * from users where upper(first_name) = '"+search+"';"

Although the above code is also bad practice from security point of view , you should use string formatting , but i dont remember exactly how that works so i wrote it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the str.upper() method:

```
{% elif  student.department.upper() != "MATHS DEPARTMENT" %}
    Maths department
{% endif %}
```

Similarly for lower cases

```
similarly, student.department.lower() != "maths department"
```